# Error using ' Transpose on ND array is not defined?

Tags: matlab, matrix, transpose, permute

I am getting  error for my below code: `temp=reshape(img',irow*icol,1);`

```
   Error message:Error using  ' 
   Transpose on ND array is not defined.
```

What is solution for this. I think I have to use permute(A,order) command. But I dont know how to use this command in my code. Do you know any solution?

```
 for i=1:M
str=strcat(int2str(i),'.jpg');   %concatenates two strings that form the name of the image
eval('img=imread(str);');
subplot(ceil(sqrt(M)),ceil(sqrt(M)),i)
imshow(img)
if i==3
    title('Training set','fontsize',18)
end
drawnow;
[irow icol]=size(img);    % get the number of rows (N1) and columns (N2)
temp=reshape(img',irow*icol,1);     %creates a (N1*N2)x1 matrix
S=[S temp];         %X is a N1*N2xM matrix after finishing the sequence
                    %this is our S
end
```

Comment: `[irow icol C]=size(img); temp=reshape(img',irow*icol*C,1);` Might work.

Comment: Sir I tried this still iam getting error:Error using  ' 
   Transpose on ND array is not defined.

Comment: You can't transpose a matrix of more than two dimensions. Why do you need to transpose exactly?

Comment: Actually iam doing face recognition using eigen faces.So i have to convert each colored face images of dimensions(irow *icol) present in training set into face vector of (irow*icol)*1 matrix.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the code was designed for grey scale images. For matrices with more than two dimensions, you have to use `permute`. One solution could be:

```
[irow icol d]=size(img);
temp=reshape(permute(img,[2,1,3]),[irow*icol,d]);
```

Which results in a nx3 matrix, each column corresponding to one colour. You have to change the last line as well, but I don't know what you are expecting. Maybe take a look at `cat`

Comment: I used your above code but stil iam getting error.Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Comment: Actually iam doing face recognition using eigen faces.So i have to convert each colored face images of dimensions(irow *icol) present in training set into face vector of (irow*icol)*1 matrix

Comment: I updated my answer, `size` did not return the number of columns the way you used it.

Comment: Sorry  i got output for that.Thanx for your solution.

Comment: Same problem iam getting in this line. InImage=reshape(double(InputImage)',irow*icol,1); Even i replaced this code with InImage=reshape(permute(double(InputImage,[2,1,3]),irow*icol,1)); but iam getting error:too many input arguements.Would you help me?

Comment: InImage=reshape(double(InputImage)',irow*icol,1);  how can i replace this code with permute?

Comment: @user3448813: Use the same code from my answer. Use `permute` to swap frist and second dimension. Then use reshape to get a nx3 matrix.